# Spring boot like module maven project change parent

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have project

```
-MyProject
    main.pom
  - spring-boot
    spring-boot.pom
  - maven module
    module.pom
  - maven module2
    module2.pom
```

`MyProject` is parent with vwrsions in property.
`module` and `module2` chields and has parnet - `MyProject`

For example in main pom:

```
<properties>
    <spring.ws.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
    ....
  </properties>
```

and in `module` and `module2` pom:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Because:

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>main.project</artifactId>
        <groupId>a.project</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

But in spring boot module already parent:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

How can I change parent to `MyProject` and use spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the Spring Boot parent pom definition in the dependency management section of your parent pom instead.

```
<dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent